# Login to website with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to login to a website, however I can't manage to. I am totally new to web-scraping hence my difficulties.

I have already read many posts and tutorials about this and tried different options. I am guessing that the problem is website specific and I can't find the right keys to pass to the `post` method.
I can login to the page normally using my web browser.I can't using this script though.

```python
import requests
from lxml import html

session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = "https://app.foodcoops.at/fruchtgenuss/login"
headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
           'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}

result = session_requests.get(login_url)
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
hidden_inputs = tree.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')

form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
form["nick"] = "<username>"
form["password"] = "<password>"
form["commit"] = "Anmelden"

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url, 
    data = form,
   headers = headers
)
```

Below is the error I am getting after I `post` the request:

> `Response [404]`

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem:
Thanks to Heikki's post i solved part of the problem:
The `authenticity_token` had to be retrieved from the `https://app.foodcoops.at/fruchtgenuss/login` url.
The credentials had to be posted to `https://app.foodcoops.at/fruchtgenuss/session` though. This made the trick.
Thank you very much for all the answers.
Below the code which worked:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

session_requests = requests.session()
# url to retrieve the authentication_token 
login_url = "https://app.foodcoops.at/fruchtgenuss/login"
# url to post the credentials
session_url = "https://app.foodcoops.at/fruchtgenuss/sessions"
headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
           'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}

result = session_requests.get(login_url)
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
hidden_inputs = tree.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')

form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
form["nick"] = "<username>"
form["password"] = "<password>"
form["commit"] = "Login"

result = session_requests.post(
    session_url, 
    data = form,
   headers = headers
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`404` can be returned not to expose information, or simply that page is not existing. So it is really hard to tell what is going on.

Good point is that they are open source. Please setup their system locally - from [github](https://github.com/foodcoopsat/foodsoft), and track problem server side.

Comment: The page is existing and when i session_requests.get(login_url) i get response 200. The problem rises whenever i try to post the login informations. I am also able to login via web-browser with no problem. I can't using my script though.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the html in the login page you see that the server expects you to post your credentials to /fruchtgenuss/sessions

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/fruchtgenuss/sessions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="bgn5GP0XBCraMSxjaYfrq8wTeTMIlSiYdcc4hJhAJFr25B6Jaynezd+IgMX0OgjR4SlMqXWD8G87RyE/+AglPA==" />
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="nick">
    User
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank yu for this hint: this solved ineed the problem of response being 404. Now i get a correct response 200. I still can not login though. The response is the same page as the login page.